# getting undefined value:app script

Tags: javascript

Here, i am trying to send a mail to `replyEmail` specified below. But it is giving as `undefined` value. Why its happening even though i am giving correct email id in google form? Some times its coming correct. But for another time its giving as `undefined` value.

```js
function sendEmail(e) {
    /**
    var email = e.values[1];
    var item = e.values[2]; 
    var cost = e.values[3];
    */

    var serviceInformation = e.values[1],
        language = e.values[2],
        meetingType = e.values[3],
        eventDate = e.values[4],
        clientName = e.values[5],
        detailedDirections = e.values[6],
        onSitePOCName = e.values[7],
        onSitePOCNumber = e.values[8],
        department = e.values[9],
        contactPhoneNumber = e.values[10],
        approval = e.values[11];  //the one we need to modif,
        requestorEmail = e.values[12],
        managerEmail = e.values[13],
        Language2 = e.values[14],
        interpreterName = e.values[15],
        interpreterAgency = e.values[16],
        dateConformationSent = e.values[17],
        specialNotes = e.values[18];


    var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/richmond.k12.va.us/s/AKfycbwuRr1boKTH0v1mprWmc7PE66_mQ_dmPE0lyWb7vkfiyW3pn31b/exec';


    // might be that the & needs to be a ?
    var approve = url + '?approval=true' + '?reply=' + requestorEmail;
    var reject = url + '?approval=false' + '?reply=' + requestorEmail;

    var html = "<HTML><body>"+
        "<h2>please review</h2><br />"
        +"<P>" + language +"  " + serviceInformation
        +"<p>" + meetingType+ "  on   "+ eventDate + "    for " +clientName
        +"<p>" + "Location: "+ department
        +"<p>" + "requester: "+ requestorEmail+ "  "+
        "<p>"+

        "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
        "<p>"+

        "<a href=" +reject+">Reject</a><br />"+
    "</HTML></body>";

    var html = [
        "<html>",
            "<body>",
                "<h2>please review</h2> <br/>",
                "<p>" + language +"  " + serviceInformation,
                "<p>" + meetingType + " on " + eventDate + " for " + clientName,
                "<p>Location: " + department,
                "<p>Requester: " + requestorEmail,
                "<p><a href=" + approve + ">Approve</a><br/>",
                "<p><a href=" + reject + ">Reject</a><br />",
            "</body>",
        "</html>";
    ].join('');

    MailApp.sendEmail(managerEmail, "Approval Request", "what no html?", {
        htmlBody: html
    });
}


function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication(),
        aprovalResponce = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved.' : 'Sorry, you need to reschedule',
        msg = "Your manager said :" + aprovalResponce;

    var replyEmail = e.parameter.reply; // !!!

    Logger.log(replyEmail);

    MailApp.sendEmail(replyEmail, "Approval Request", msg);

    var helloWorldLabel = app.createLabel(msg);
    app.add(helloWorldLabel); 

    return app;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your query parameters are malformed. They should be `example.com/test?param1=true&param2=something`. Looking at your comment, I would guess that you had it correct at one point.

Answer (score 0):

Its because space is not accepted while parsing the data in google script.It should be encoded and then the data is to be send.It can be encoded using **encodeURIcomponent()**.